# Java Streams with combining multiple rows to one

Tags: java, java-stream

My code consists of a class with 10 variables. The class will get the data from a database table and the results from it is a List. Here is a sample class:

```
@Data
class pMap {
    long id;
    String rating;
    String movieName;
}
```

The data will be as follows:

```
id=1, rating=PG-13, movieName=
id=1, rating=, movieName=Avatar
id=2, rating=, movieName=Avatar 2
id=2, rating=PG, movieName=
```

I want to combine both the rows to a single row grouping by `id` using Java streams. The end result should like this `Map<Long, pMap>`:

```
1={id=1, rating=PG-13, movieName=Avatar},
2={id=2, rating=PG, movieName=Avatar 2}
```

I am not sure how I can get the rows combined to one by pivoting them.

Comment: group with a combiner should do it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how to combine the results with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [toMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) to achieve this:

```java
Map<Long, pMap> myMap = myList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x.id, Function.identity(),
                (x1, x2) -> new pMap(x1.id, x1.rating != null ? x1.rating : x2.rating, x1.movieName != null ? x1.movieName : x2.movieName)));
```

I am passing two functions to toMap method:

1. First one is a key mapper. It maps an element to a key of the map. In this case, I want the key to be the id.
2. The second one is a value mapper. I want the value to be the actual pMap so this is why I am passing the identity function.
3. The third argument is a merger function that tells how to merge two values with the same id.

Comment: Edited to handle the merge.

Comment: @Cristian Riță This does not merge the data from multiple rows. It is just printing the first row per Id

Comment: Check the edited answer. For your input it returns the following map: {1=Id: 1 rating: PG-13 movieName: Avatar, 2=Id: 2 rating: PG movieName: Avatar 2}

Comment: @CristianRiță well done, this looks good!